# Layout_below is not working in my listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, android-toolbar

I have custom toolbar and i want my listview to be below Toolbar . But listview is appearing on the toolbar and my layout_below is not working . I know many question have been asked before . But nothing is working . Please Help me

below is my layoutxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="faisal.home.com.tafaqquhfiddin.DuwaListView">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/MyListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
   ></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbarlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is because your linear layout on toolbarlayout.xml takes all the height of your screen, because you specify it as match parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question was already answered by other users...

I just would like to add more information.

Your layout can be much simpler. You don't need use `RelativeLayout`. Just use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` instead. This way, you will have:

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="faisal.home.com.tafaqquhfiddin.DuwaListView">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MyListView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar Layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: can you help me on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687159/what-is-metadata-and-what-is-the-use-of-it-in-android)

Comment: @FaisalAhmed Done :)

Comment: help me once again please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854909/can-fonts-and-its-size-can-be-changed-from-xml-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `LinearLayout` from your `toolbarlayout.xml`. So your `toolbarlayout.xml` should look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it'll work.

my layoutxml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="faisal.home.com.tafaqquhfiddin.DuwaListView">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MyListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
       ></ListView>

</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

The root layout of toolbarlayout.xml height is "match_parent" change it to "wrap_content". Use the below code it will works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="faisal.home.com.tafaqquhfiddin.DuwaListView">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/MyListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbarlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```