# What is the value of the following meta data and how is it set?

Tags: android, metadata

While getting familiar with a library project I stumbled upon this meta data:

```
<meta-data android:name="private_client_id" android:value="${private_client_id}" />
```

which is later accessed like this:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
String senderId = bundle.getString("private_client_id");
```

What is the exact value of `private_client_id` and when is that value set. Shouldn't meta data be set during compile time?

Comment: As described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687159/what-is-metadata-and-what-is-the-use-of-it-in-android  metadata is is basically an additional option to store information that can be accessed through the entire project. In this case,`<meta-data>` is defined outside `<activity>` tag and inside `<application>` tag..  In your case as it is a string its value would be simply : **${private_client_id}**

Comment: So there's nothing that is assigned to ${private_client_id} during compile. It's assigned later on in the work flow of the library. I see now. Thank you!