# How to show meta-data of an installed app by adb?

Tags: android, android-manifest

There is a way to add some metadata to AndroidManifest.xml for an app, a service or an activity (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38699357/1263771):

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <meta-data android:name="my_test_metagadata" android:value="testValue" />
    ......
</application>
```

How to get that metadata from the installed app by the adb command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not do this directly as far as I know.
But here is a workaround:

1. Look for apk from installed package using `adb shell pm list -f | grep com.aaa.bbb.ccc`. The format will be like `package:${path}=com.aaa.bbb.ccc`
2. Pull apk from device. On some of the devices this can be done directly, but on the other devices, you will have to copy apk to sdcard using `cp ${path} /sdcard`. Then pull apk using `adb pull`.
3. Use `aapt` in android build-tools to view metadata like `aapt l -a ${apk_local_path} | grep -A 2 metadata`. The command after `grep` can be changed as you need. The above example is for list all meta-data with non-array value